# Wave of Light Range

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

As far as I can tell, when you use Wave of Light, it seems to often miss the first object in front of you.

Can it not damage anything that the bell actually lands on? Even though it seems like when I use it I move very close to the targeted enemy.

Do I need to do this attack from a greater distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the skill is worded (see below, emphasis mine) seems to make it clear that the bell falling does the immediate damage, and then the line of damage goes out from there.

> Focuses a wave of light that **crushes** enemies for 215% weapon damage as Holy, followed by an additional 45% weapon damage as Holy to all enemies in a line.

I do not know if the radius of the initial damage is known. It could be that you are pointed in slightly the wrong direction, or that you are actually running slightly past the enemies before triggering the ability. It's also possible that, due to latency, you or the monsters are not exactly where you appear to be on your monitor.

But I think based on the description and animation that the initial damage is intended to be at melee range, under the dropping bell.

Comment: Probably the lag, my latency is low, but it seems to be hitting me pretty bad anyway...I will play around with it more to see what I can figure out. Thanks!

Comment: There's a small distance between the character and the Bell, so it may be that. Been awhile since I used the skill.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small gap between the player and where the bell drops that a monster can be in where they won't get hit by the bell

It's usually about the size of the small imps the Fallen Prophets resurrect, so most larger monsters will get hit by the Bell regardless of where they're standing, although smaller monsters can get close enough to not be hit by it.

[image: Screenshot]